# How to find URL that a page redirects to

Tags: http, url, lua

In my code, I have a URL to a page that redirects to another, whose URL I need. It doesn't seem to be contained within the page or headers. I'm new to Lua and StackOverflow and I don't know all the ins and outs of it, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

Read much more about the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol (and [HTTP header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) and [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), notably [301 Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)), and about HTML (e.g. [`<meta` refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh))

Redirections can be done in both. You'll use some HTTP client library such as [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (see its [lua curl](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) binding) and you need to parse the entire HTTP response.